# Xamarin library conflict error

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I used ikvm to turn my .jar into .dll with the command "ikvmc.exe -out:myAPI.dll C:/.../myLibs/*.jar"

I imported the following only:

[image: Xamarin Imports]

Now I get the error "You have Jar libraries, resources.jar, that have the identical name with inconsistent file contents. Please make sure to remove any conflicting libraries in EmbeddedJar, InputJar and AndroidJavaLibrary. XamForm.Droid"

How to fix?

Comment: There is a [case](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/23538/identical-jar-libraries-with-inconsistent-file-contents) similar to yours

Comment: Yes, but the hotfix suggested in Xamarin forum's link is in 2014 for before. I'm using the latest version. Additionally, I'm unable to find "General > Target Framework" in the options.

Comment: Hi, have you solved it?